# ionic 3 load js and css component after changing pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to use a bootstrap template in my ionic 3 app.
I have 2 pages LoginPage and HomePage. In my HomePage I have the template's calendar widget which is fullcalendar.js ... When I launch the homepage at first my calendar is displayed but if when launch loginpage at first and I switch to homePage the fullcalendar not displayed.
in my index.html I have put all template css path and js
this is my LoginPage html:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card card-shadowed px-50 py-30 w-400px mx-auto" style="max-width: 100%">
      <h5 class="text-uppercase">Sign in</h5>
      <br>

      <form class="form-type-material">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mail" name="mail" [(ngModel)]="user.mail">
          <label for="mail">Username</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group flexbox flex-column flex-md-row">


          <a class="text-muted hover-primary fs-13 mt-2 mt-md-0" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-bold btn-block btn-primary" (click)="onLogin(user)" type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <p class="text-center text-muted fs-13 mt-20">Vous n'avez pas de compte ? <a class="text-primary fw-500" href="#">Creez-en un </a></p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

in the login.ts page i've put js and css path like this:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Users} from "../../shared/model/users";
import {AngularFireAuth} from "angularfire2/auth";
import {HomePage} from "../home/home";

/**
 * Generated class for the LoginPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage{


  user = {} as Users;

  constructor(private autf: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }


  async onLogin(user: Users){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

}
```

and my homePage html:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card card-shadowed px-50 py-30 w-400px mx-auto" style="max-width: 100%">
      <h5 class="text-uppercase">Sign in</h5>
      <br>

      <form class="form-type-material">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mail" name="mail" [(ngModel)]="user.mail">
          <label for="mail">Username</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group flexbox flex-column flex-md-row">


          <a class="text-muted hover-primary fs-13 mt-2 mt-md-0" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-bold btn-block btn-primary" (click)="onLogin(user)" type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <p class="text-center text-muted fs-13 mt-20">Vous n'avez pas de compte ? <a class="text-primary fw-500" href="#">Creez-en un </a></p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

need some solution
ps: sorry for my english :)